# android TextWatcher with ListView refresh everytime

Tags: android, firebase, textwatcher

I'm trying to highlight row in listview every time it changes it realtime database (firebase). It works semi correctly, because when I change something on position "1" its highlight correct, but next I change e.g. position "2", and both positsions (1 and 2) are highlighted, etc. Rather my comparing (current object field with CharSequences) in if statement are incorrect, I think so, but I have no idea how do it properly.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {    
...
...
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if ((user.name.equals(s.toString())) == false) {


                finalConvertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                new CountDownTimer(500, 100) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        finalConvertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                    }
                }.start();

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this, by adding`finalConvertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);`

between if statement and `finalConvertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);`